# Regex ignore middle part of capture

Tags: c#, regex

I want a single regex that when applied to : "firstsecondthird" will match "firstthird" (in single group, ie in C# `Match.Value` will be equal to "firstthird").

Is that possible? we can ignore suffix or prefix , but middle?

Comment: Why are you putting the restriction on it that it has to be in a single group?  I don't think that's possible.

Comment: just wondering whether its possible, it would be easier if it was. if not ill go with replace no problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

match a string that starts with 'first', has zero or more other characters, then ends with 'third'.  Is that what you mean?

```
"^first(.*)third$"
```

Or, do you mean if you find a string 'firstsecondthird', ditch everything apart from 'first' and 'third'?

```
replace("^(first)second(third)$", "$1$2")
```

Comment: it will match firstsecondthird, not firstthird I believe, which is not what I want. Or I need regex replace for that?

Comment: no, it also will match firstthird as well.  .* means zero or more, so there doesn't need to be anything in the place of 'second'.

Comment: yeah, effect has to be like from replace in your example, but I was wondering whether that is possible without replace maybe, since we arent reordering anything I thought there could be a way.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no facility to make a single match group containing non-contiguous text from the target string.  You will need to use replace, or glue together the matching groups into a new string.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is not possible to do with a single regular expression. You will have to use a call to `replace();` as follows:

```
String inputVar = "firstsecondthird";
String resultVar = Regex.replace(inputVar, "^(first)second(third)$", "$1$2");
```

which can (typically...) be inserted into an expression as necessary

Answer (score -1):

I know this question was asked several years ago at this point, but for the sake of anyone who is still coming here looking for the answer, there is a way, not like any of the other answers, that will exclude a part in the middle with only one expression.

The trick is to use 'non-capturing groups'. This feature allows one to search using an expression that includes a group that is not included in the result.

The syntax of this is as follows:

```
(?:Groups Contents)
```

This will be matched with the rest of the expression, but that group is excluded from the returned result.

e.g. If you apply the following expression to a list of names separated by newlines,

```
\w{2,} (?:Micheal |James )\w{2,}
```

It will match every person with the middle names of 'Micheal' or 'James', but only return their first and last name.

In the following list, matches are italicized, returned text is in bold:

- Duke Jamesson
- Bob James
- ***Bob*** Micheal **Jones**
- James Anderson
- ***Joseph*** Micheal **Hetton**
- ***Bill*** James **Johnson**
- George Ronald McCarthy

Comment: You can't exclude a part in the middle of a match - PERIOD. This answer is wrong. See [triplee's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769529/3832970) that is the real answer to the question. The [duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768405/3832970) is a *workaround* that does not always fit all scenarios.